# Область видимости модулей Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Есть два модуля ( использую синтаксис `es6` )

**Модуль 1**

```
exports.someFunc = function () {
    return someVar;
}
```

**Модуль 2**

```
let Module1 = require("Module1.js");

let someVar = 10;

console.log( Module1.someFunc() ); 
/* Выбрасывает ошибку, что someVar не определена*/
```

Можно ли как-нибудь заставить функцию *первого модуля* видеть локальные переменные *второго модуля*.

**P.S.** Передача переменной, как *параметр* функции первого модуля не очень подходит
 В реальности, *первый модуль*, это список функций , которые вызываются во *втором модуле*. 
( функций очень много, поэтому решил вынести их в отдельный модуль).

Comment: Даже если получится так сделать, это антипаттерн. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency

Comment: Не понимаю, что мешает все таки передать переменную в качестве параметра? Она так и так попадет в память. К тому же это самое очевидное и простое решение.

Comment: @Razzwan, количество параметров будет увеличиваться, и не хочется видеть в коде, что нить аля
`func(var1, var2, var3... varN)`я попробую вариант Olson-a

Comment: Да, и это получается DI контейнер. Лучшее решение на данный момент.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нет, нельзя, и хорошо, что так, потому что это нарушает принцип [инкапсуляции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)).

Но все таки можно использовать объект, который оба модуля видят:

module1.js

```
let data = {};

exports.data = data;

exports.someFunc = function () {
  return data.someVar;
};
```

module2.js

```
let module1 = require("./module1.js");

module1.data.someVar = 10;

console.log(module1.someFunc());
```